# We picked up our cockatiels egg and we were about to candle it but we felt something hard rattling inside is it alive?

Tags: birds, cockatiels, eggs

The egg was darker than others and we didn't candle it because we were too worried we might damage the egg further.

Comment: Welcome at pets.SE! As much as I know, candeling eggs does not damage them.

Answer (score 0):

Candling an egg will not damage it unless you are using a literal candle and hold it too close. That being said, I'd say you should not use a candle and instead try a flashlight or something that does not involve fire. I do not raise birds, so I don't know much about them, but I did do some research and found a wikihow [article](https://www.wikihow.life/Candle-an-Egg) about how to do it. There was not anything on egg damage, so I'd assume damage is not a risk.

As for the hard thing inside the egg, I cannot answer that, because it could be a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

If an egg is rattling, it's a dead egg.